# Quicklook Slide show from files - small photos

Tags: finder, photos, quicklook

M1 Macbook.  12.4 Monterey.  I have a folder with jpgs.  I select a few of the files and hit the spacebar for quick look.  I have a 'dummies' book for Big Sur, and it looks like it shows the picture in a large format, filling up the window.  And if you maximize the window, the picture is pretty much filling the screen.  What I am seeing in a maximized window is the photo severely minimized.  It's on the left edge of the window (with a big white border) and extends to about 25% of the screen.  Next to the window is a file description (it's name, size, and date taken).  Then the right half of the window is totally unused.
How can I make the picture fill up the entire window?  I don't want to see the file info and the photo is large enough to fill up the screen (it actually has more pixels than my screen)